# in iOS native app, open unity3D on button click

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, uibutton

I'm trying to open Unity3D on click of `UIButton` using `storyboard` by following this [tutorial](https://the-nerd.be/2015/11/13/integrate-unity-5-in-a-native-ios-app-with-xcode-7/#comment-568).

I'm getting use of undeclared identifier `AppDelegate.h` in `UnityAppController` [file](http://www.screencast.com/t/uJSkiny8tZ) and if remain previous code which is below.

```
inline UnityAppController*  GetAppController(){
   return (UnityAppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

Getting error http://www.screencast.com/t/iSUrpt639XD. Similar QA does not helped me.

Comment: is this objective C or other language?

Comment: @SaurabhJain objective c and c++ both (unity code is in c++)

Comment: clear the project and run again